# How can I hide (or disable) the add item option in form view? In Odoo 9

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

I have a custom form for sale.order view.

I want to allow to edit the lines but I dont want to allow to add new lines.

Basically I want to delete or hide the option of "add new item" located at the bottom of the lines.

There is that in the code:

```xml
...
<notebook>
  <page string="Lineas de pedido">
      <field name="order_line" mode="tree,kanban"
             attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ('done','cancel'))]}">
...
```

But modifying this, affects to whole edition.

Only for more information, I saw that the class applied to the row is:

```
oe_form_field_x2many_list_row_add
```

But this is standard for all forms, and I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to remove the additem just disable create in embaded tree of x2many field:

```xml
<field name="order_line" mode="tree,kanban"
             attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ('done','cancel'))]}">
            <tree create="0" ....>
              ....
              .....
```